# PostgreSQL unique value acreoss multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, constraints, unique

I have PostgreSQL table

```
id    ColA    ColB
------------------
1     'a'     'b'
2     'c'     'd'
```

I want to make values in ColA and ColB to be unique across both columns i.e. any of these inserts would be forbidden:

```
INSERT INTO table (ColA,ColB) values('a','e');
INSERT INTO table (ColA,ColB) values('z','a');
INSERT INTO table (ColA,ColB) values('d','g');
```

and any of these inserts would be allowed:

```
INSERT INTO table (ColA,ColB) values('z','e');
INSERT INTO table (ColA,ColB) values('l','k');
```

So

```
CONSTRAINT unique_name UNIQUE (ColA,ColB)
```

is not suited, because it will allow any of previous 4 inserts.

Answer (score 5):

Sadly, this cannot be solved easily with simple unique contraints / indexes (if it can be solved with them at all).

What you need, is an [exclusion](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION) [constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html#SQL-CREATETABLE-EXCLUDE): the ability to exclude some rows, based on something like *collision*. Unique constraints are just specific exclusion constraints (they are based on equality *collisions*).

So, in theory, you just need to exclude every `row1`, where there is already a `row2`, for which this expression is true: `ARRAY[row1.cola, row1.colb] && ARRAY[row2.cola, row2.colb]`

This index *could* do the job (currently only `gist` indexes support exclusion constraints):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD CONSTRAINT table_name_exclusion
  EXCLUDE USING gist ((ARRAY[cola, colb]) WITH &&);
```

**But** unfortunately, there is no default operator class for arrays (which uses `gist`). There is an [`intarray` module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html), which provides one for only `integer` arrays, but nothing for `text` arrays.

If you really want to work this out, you can always abuse the [`range` types](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rangetypes.html) (f.ex. I used the adjacent `-|-` operator, which handles all the cases, which cannot be handled with `unique`) ...

```
-- there is no built-in type for text ranges neither,
-- but it can can be created fairly easily:
CREATE TYPE textrange AS RANGE (
  SUBTYPE = text
);

ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD CONSTRAINT table_name_exclusion
  EXCLUDE USING gist ((textrange(least(cola, colb), greatest(cola, colb))) WITH -|-);

-- the exclusion constraint above does not handle all situations:

ALTER TABLE table_name
  ADD CONSTRAINT table_name_check
  CHECK (cola is distinct from colb); -- without this, empty ranges could be created,
                                      -- which are not adjacent to any other range

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX table_name_unique
  ON table_name ((ARRAY[least(cola, colb), greatest(cola, colb)]));
     -- without this, duplicated rows could be created,
     -- because ranges are not adjacent to themselves
```

... but I'm afraid, your original problem could be solved much easier with a little database refactoring; which brings us to the question: what problem, do you want to solve with this?

Comment: I have a similar problem: a user table has two columns for email addresses. One for the regular email and another one for a new not validated email. Now I want them to be unique no matter whether they are validated already or not yet.