# Unique among two columns

Tags: postgresql, unique-constraint

Assuming Postgresql >= 10, is there a way to constrain a table to have unique values in *two* (or more) columns? That is, a value can only appear in one of columns. I'd like to avoid triggers as long as I can. For a single column that would be trivial.

Let's have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  col1 INTEGER,
  col2 INTEGER
);
```

So it should be

```
1 2
4 3
5 7
```

While `8 4` would be impossible, because there is `4 3` already.

So far I figured it could be possible constrain `EXCLUDE ((ARRAY[col1, col2]) WITH &&)`, but it seems unsupported (yet?):

```
ERROR:  operator &&(anyarray,anyarray) is not a member of operator family "array_ops"
```

This requirement is also could be seem as an empty inner-joined table (`on a.col1 = b.col2`). I guess I could use triggers, but I'd like to avoid them as long as I can.

P. S. Here is [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42205501/unique-key-on-two-columns-commutatively).

Comment: Can you explain why you need it? I think that it breaks the [Nothing but the key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#"Nothing_but_the_key") rule. Or maybe it's a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: How do you use those two numbers? Why can't you create a table with a single integer column and e.g. a `varchar` column indicating if it's used as "col1" or "col2" (those names aren't really helpful). The you could use a simple unique index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: `col1` and `cols2` really mean that the values are equally important and interchangeable. They can't be in one column, because those values should compose pairs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty user [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776251/postgresql-unique-value-acreoss-multiple-columns) is quite close to what you're looking to achieve but, as mentioned in the answer. There's no **true** way to do this as it is not common practice.
In programming, when something like this happens, it would be better to perform some database refactoring to find an alternative, more ideal, solution.
Hope to be of any help!